# Domain Acces + Internationalization + Metatag: How?

Tags: 7, domain-access, meta-tags, i18n-l10n

I am using those three modules i mentioned in title in my installation.
I was able to localize it pretty much, but what about meta tags for different domains and languages? I am also using [Domains Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/domains_metatag) module, but it doesn't allow to localize the domain's metatag for a front page, for example.

Is there a possibility to make it happen? Thanks in advance!